# Multiple Languages - Language files OR Langages Database?

Tags: localization

I'm developing a website from scratch. It supposed to be a multi-lang website.

My question is, how should I do that?

Manage language files or manage language database tables?
I'm using MySQL, it you need to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can do either way, it is a choice of opinion. I prefer files, because from my sight they are easier to translate and because of that you can even let other people without so much technical know-how do the translation of the files :)

Answer (score 0):

i recommend using a file "StringManager Class"

```
public static final String stringManagerBinFile = "/StringManager_en.data";
public static final int ABOUT = 0;
public static final int ACCOUNT = 1;
public static final int PASS = 2;
public static final int CONTACT = 3;
......

public static String getData (int header) {
    //Load string from stringManagerBinFile, if user change language, you might be change stringManagerBinFile PATH
}
```

In your code you can use:

```
String about = getData(ABOUT);
//repaint your GUI
```